# Can't show upload file with eloquent laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am bulid website that user can make a post and comment on it. The comment can have many file. Create comment and file work fine but when show the post, that just show post and comment, not with comment's file.

```
//Post.php
public function commentsPost()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\commentPost');
}

//CommentPost.php
public function post()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
public function filesPost()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\FilePost');
}

//FilePost.php
public function commentsPost()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CommentPost');
}
```

This my `CommentController.php`

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    if ($post != null) {
        return view('post.show', compact('post'));

    } else {
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'This post does not exist.');
    }
}
```

And `show.blade.php`

```
@foreach($post->commentsPost as $comment)   
  <h2>{{ $comment->message }} by {{ $comment->user->name }}</h2>
  @foreach($comment->filesPost->all() as $file)
    <h5>{{ $file->filename }}</h5>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I use `dd($post->commentsPost->filesPost->all());` and error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$filesPost`

How to show the comment also the file? I use Laravel 5

Comment: try dd($file); in the middle of the second foreach!

Comment: no different result, still post and comment without the file

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@foreach($post->commentsPost as $comment)   
  <h2>{{ $comment->message }} by {{ $comment->user->name }}</h2>
  @foreach($comment->filesPost() as $file)
    <h5>{{ $file->filename }}</h5>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: What something missing on controller?